# How to write this query which contains a variable?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with multiple labels:

```
create(p:SmartPhone:Phone:Product {name:'iPhoneX'})-[r:productOf]->(c:Company {name:"Apple"})

create(p:SmartTV:Product {name:string})
```

In creating my query, I have to parse my query from user's question. For example, "Do you have Apple's smart phone?". In my code, the label in the MATCH statement would be a variable $smartPhone. I can't hard-code the different categories because it has to be parsed from users' question dynamically and there are too many such categories.

```
match (p:SmartPhone)-[r:productOf]->(c:Company {name:'Apple'})
return p
```

Here I can't use p:SmartPhone, it has to be something like "$SmartPhone". Is there a way to write this query? It seems a very common need. How to handle this type of question? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the suggestions in @InverseFalcon's comment (to another answer), you can alter your data model by making each `Product` node related to one (or more) `ProductType` node(s).

For example, to create a new `Product` (whose name is given by `$prodName`) that has 2 different product types (whose types are in the `$types` list parameter), made by a `Company` whose name is in `$compName`, you could use the query below. You should also create indexes for `:Company(name)` and `ProductType(type)` to speed up the `MATCH`es.

```
MATCH (c:Company {name: $compName})
CREATE (p:Product {name: $prodName})-[:productOf]->(c)
MATCH (t:ProductType)
WHERE t.type IN $types
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_TYPE]->(t);
```

With this proposed data model, here is one way to find `Product`s of a given type (`$type`) from a given company (`$compName`), you could use this query:

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[:productOf]->(:Company {name: $compName})
WHERE (:ProductType {type: $type})<-[:HAS_TYPE]-(p)
RETURN p;
```

You can also find `Product`s from a given `Company` (`$compName`) that have all the types in a `$types` list:

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[:productOf]->(:Company {name: $compName})
WHERE ALL(x IN $types WHERE (:ProductType {type: x})<-[:HAS_TYPE]-(p))
RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Labels` and relationship's `type` can't be parameterized in a cypher query.

So you have two choices :

- to create the query inside your application code
- to use APOC that has some procedures to dynamicaly create nodes and relationships

Comment: Alternatively, you could alter your model. Anything that is parametrizable should probably be a property. This could be in place of labels, or as a supplement to them, if they are still useful in hardcoded contexts.

Comment: Adding as property is one option.